# What is the food source for the hungries after Melanie’s action?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-girl-with-all-the-gifts

In *The Girl with All the Gifts* (2016), it certainly appears that hungries only eat non-infected humans (and the occasional animal).

Once Melanie has set fire, thereby opening the pods, everyone will be infected. So what will the hungries eat from then on?